# The close icon(X) is not visible for Jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created the jquery dialog. It does not show the close(x) button in IE, but in FF it shows correctly. Please help me to solve this issue.

Jquery Version: 1.11.1
Jquery UI version: 1.10.4

Code:

```
<!-- ui-dialog -->
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
    <p>Test Me.</p>
</div>

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                 width : 400,
              resizable : false,
        buttons: [
        {
            text: "Yes",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        {
            text: "No",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: No. This I use jquery only.

Comment: It's showing in IE just fine for me : http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/vdsnw33e/

Comment: Look try this, change the order of how you load the files, load first Jquery UI and later Jquery or viceversa

Comment: Please show us how are you loading your files. Your code is all good. No ERROR

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading the script in correct order:

1. jQuery core library `<script src="..../jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>`
2. Bootstrap js (if using) `<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`
3. jQuery UI library  `<script src="..../jquery-ui-1.10.4.j.js"></script>`